# Permission error when running .exe from pyinstaller but .py works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

EDIT:
Complete rewrite of the question following comments.

The code below runs OK if I run it from the interpreter but if I run the same program as a .exe file generated with pyinstaller it fails with an
`[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:/test/test.docx'`. Also, if I run the same exe from an **admin cmd window** I get the **same error**.

This has been driving me nuts for hours. Any ideas on how to debug this? (this is on a windows 10 enterprise PC with python 3.6).

```
"""
        test.py
"""
import os
import zipfile
file = r'c:/test/test.docx'
print(f"{file} os.path.exists? {os.path.exists(file)}")
print(f"{file} os.path.isfile? {os.path.isfile(file)}")
print(f"open {file}")
with open(file, "rb") as f:
    print(f"fread & print first 20 chars:")
    print(f.read()[0:20])
```

If I run this code with python:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>..\python test.py
c:/test/test.docx os.path.exists? True
c:/test/test.docx os.path.isfile? True
open c:/test/test.docx
fread & print first 20 chars:
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00\xecq\x1c\xa0\xf0\x01'
```

Now I generate an exe file:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pyinstaller --onefile test.py
338 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
339 INFO: Python: 3.6.8
340 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
344 INFO: wrote C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\test.spec
352 INFO: UPX is not available.
358 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\Scripts']
359 INFO: checking Analysis
367 INFO: Building because C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\test.py changed
368 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
387 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
427 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
7130 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
7305 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
7352 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
7508 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\test.py
7516 INFO: Processing module hooks...
7517 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
7998 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
8008 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
8519 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
8519 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
8531 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
8763 INFO: Looking for eggs
8764 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python36.dll
8765 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
8778 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\build\test\warn-test.txt
8849 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\build\test\xref-test.html
8884 INFO: checking PYZ
8890 INFO: Building because toc changed
8890 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz
9629 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
9664 INFO: checking PKG
9673 INFO: Building because toc changed
9674 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
11417 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
11427 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
11427 INFO: checking EXE
11437 INFO: Building because toc changed
11438 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
11445 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\dist\test.exe
11498 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

If I now runs the .exe:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>dist\test.exe
c:/test/test.docx os.path.exists? True
c:/test/test.docx os.path.isfile? True
open c:/test/test.docx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:/test/test.docx' # <<<<<<<<
[3640] Failed to execute script test
```

EDIT 2:
After more investigations, this case happens when the file is encrypted by "Azure Information Protection" with a domain level account. This DLP program is a sort of DRM to protect office files on a corporate PC for instance. What is strange is that running the code above give different results depending on the way it is launched. I would have thought that using python to launch a .py and running the coresponding .exe would use the same credentials as the user and thus produce the same results but the results are different.

Files that are encrypted have the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED bit set which you can detect with:

```
def is_encrypted(path):
    return os.stat(path).st_file_attributes & stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED
```

and in my case, the identity used to encrypt is something linked to the domain (don't know what yet as I didn't find documentation on it).

Comment: Can you share the `spec file` of `pyinstaller` pls?

Comment: question edited to add spec file

Comment: Hey yo, I just reproduced the code and didn't have any problem. Did you check the `.docx`'s permissions ?

Comment: Whatever the permissions are, it is not normal that running the py and the exe produce different results. + it happens with any file the user used to run the exe has access to. I'd like to be able to know with more details what the permission problem is but don't know how.I wonder if this can be linked to some DLP crap and how I can confirm this.

Comment: I also reproduced your code without problem, excepted that the zip file was corrupted when generated from pyinstaller. I had to add myZipFile.close() to make it clean (as requested by documentation). Also I noticed your spec file is not "basic". Try and  build your MRE with simply pyinstaller --onefile test2.py

Comment: I tried with pyinstaller only (no autopy) but the result is the same. [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:/test/test.docx'

Comment: Try and remove the open statement (and all the exception handling)

Comment: @wotter I do not see any other answer as: check your permissions, as brad Figueroa suggested.  There may be some unknown reasons why the exe would request different permissions. Make sure your docx file is readable and writable by everybody and retest.

Comment: @Eric Mathieu My best bet at the moment is that it is linked to something called "Azure Information Protection" but I don't know how to prove it for sure as I don't know how to get more detailed information about the error.

Comment: I did some more testing and I get the error only with MS Office files so AIP seems a good candidate. What I don't understand is why it behaves differently with the .py and the .exe. Also I could not find in AIP a good explanation of the permission issue. With the doc I have read so far I would have expected to be able to read the file and get encrypted data not get a permission error.

Comment: The trigger of the permission error seems to be the E attribute flag (I assume it means encrypted). It would be nice if python error message was more explicit...

Comment: Python as many language is relying on the os for the basic functions like accessing a file. It cannot handle any kind of configuration to provide detailed message.

Comment: @wotter Could you please do me a favour? Could you try and build you exe from an admin console and then run it from a non admin console ?

Comment: Eric, I tried what you suggested, build from an admin console and run from non admin. It stills throws the Permission error.

Comment: You may be able to reproduce the behavior by encrypting the file with another account with file/properties/attributes/advanced/encrypt to protect content.